# How to change the color of a RibbonGroup in a Ribbon control?

Tags: delphi, ribbon

Using Delphi XE.

1. Is it possible to change the color of a RibbonGroup inside the Ribbon? It has a bluish color no matter what the color scheme of the parent Ribbon component, and there is no color property.
2. Is it possible to set ant other color for the Ribbon beside the 3 built-in color schemes?

Comment: What implementation of the ribbon do you use? Is it the ribbon included with Delphi XE or a different one? For example from DevExpress.

Comment: @Wodzu: TRibbon which is the one included with Delphi XE.

Comment: This problem (1.) does not happen for me in Delphi 2009. However, apparently you need to associate a `TActionManager` to the `TRibbon` before *anything* works...

Comment: Yes, I already did that and have commands in various RibbonGroups in the Ribbon. Its just changing of the colors that I can't figure out..

Comment: If you create a *new*. *empty* VCL project with a `TRibbon` and a `TActionManager`, does it work then?

Comment: Yes it does. This means that something is messed up in my original project. I will delete the control and add it again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with native Delphi TRibbon, have a look at Erik van Bilsen's [Windows Ribbon Framework](http://www.bilsen.com/windowsribbon/index.shtml).